# How to run Microsoft Office Version : 18.2008.12711.0 with accessdatabaseengine_X64 in .NET Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office365, database-engine

I am a newbie to this platform and also to running MS Office applications with .Net. I am trying to export data from datagridview to excel sheet on click of a button. Here's my code :

```
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

 xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
 xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
 For i = 0 To DataGrdView.RowCount - 2
     For j = 0 To DataGrdView.ColumnCount - 1
         For k As Integer = 1 To DataGrdView.Columns.Count
             xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGrdView.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
             xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGrdView(j, i).Value.ToString()
         Next
     Next
 Next
 xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("E:\Student information.xlsx")
```

After executing the line,
xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

Visual Studio reports an exception as :

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Student Information System.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))."

This error is coming because I am using AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 which is released in 2016, with MS Office 365 Version : 18.2008.12711.0. with .Net Framework 4.8.

I know that I can manually repair the office and problem will be solved but I don't want my application's user to repair the office and handle this error manually instead I want to provide a functionality that automatically handles this issue and give appropriate results.

I tried deleting key Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9 in Registry Editor but this didn't work.

I also made sure that all my Office apps are running in 64 bit mode so that database driver can work properly, but I am still getting this issue.

Which changes should I implement to get rid of this trouble?

Comment: I have also tried using [SpreadSheetLight](https://spreadsheetlight.com) library instead of office automation, but, it does not support .Net Framework 4.8 .

Comment: What version of the Interop are you using?  You may need to use a later version of the Interop.

Comment: @jdweng I tried but failed.